# Change the value in one row, conditioned on a value in another row in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data-wrangling

I'm categorizing smokers and non-smokers at different time points. If someone does not smoke at one time point, but smoked at a previous time point, then their health is "Intermediate." The problem is, each time point has its own row, so I need to input a value into a row conditioned on the value in another row. How do I do this?

Here is a sample data frame. Right now I have it so that all people who don't smoke have "Ideal" health, but this is wrong, because if they smoked previously, they should have "Intermediate" health.

```
x <- data.frame(Participant = c(1,1,2,2,3),
                Time = c(1,2,1,2,1),
                Smoke_T1 = c(1,NA,0,NA,NA),
                Smoke_T2 = c(NA,0,NA,0,NA),
                Health = c("Poor",rep("Ideal",3),NA)
                )
```

This is the goal:

```
x <- data.frame(Participant = c(1,1,2,2,3),
                Time = c(1,2,1,2,1),
                Smoke_T1 = c(1,NA,0,NA,NA),
                Smoke_T2 = c(NA,0,NA,0,NA),
                Health = c("Poor","Intermediate",rep("Ideal",2),NA)
                )
```

I have tried:

```
x2 <- group_by(x,Participant) %>% 
  mutate(Health[x$Time == 2] = case_when(
    x$Smoke_T1[x$Time == 1] == 1 & x$Smoke_T2[x$Time == 2] == 0 ~ "Intermediate"
      ))
```

It throws an error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"x2 <- group_by(x,Participant) %>% 
   mutate(Health[x$Time == "2"] ="
```

The proposed solution does not have to use tidyverse. I am actually more familiar with base R, but I don't know how to condition on another row in base R, either.

Comment: What is the difference between `0` and `NA` in your data set for the two time points?

Comment: Why are there two different time points ```Time``` and two different ```Smoke_T1 or T2``` times?

Comment: 0 means doesn't smoke. 1 means smokes. NA means they didn't answer the question. As for why there are two separate columns for smoking at times 1 and 2, This is how the data was given to me. If I would have designed the data set, I would have done it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay So first I cleaned your timepoint data for clearity:

```
x <- data.frame(Participant = c(1,1,2,2,3),
                Time = c(1,2,1,2,1),
                Smoke_T1 = c(1,NA,0,NA,NA),
                Smoke_T2 = c(NA,0,NA,0,NA),
                Health = c("Poor",rep("Ideal",3),NA)
                )

x2 <- x %>% 
  # clean time points by mergeing NA in columns
  mutate(Smoker = coalesce(Smoke_T1,Smoke_T2)) %>% 
  # subset data for cleaner look
  select(Participant, Time,Smoker, Health)
```

Next is the results you want, I think:

```
x3 <- x2 %>% 
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  mutate(Health = case_when(
    Time == 1 & Smoker > 0 ~ "Poor",
    # use lag to see previous time point for T2 result
    lag(Smoker == 1) & Time == 2 & Smoker < 1 ~ "Intermediate", 
    Time == 1 & Smoker < 1 ~ "Ideal",
    #if they didnt smoke in T1 but do in T2
    lag(Smoker < 1) & Time == 2 & Smoker > 0 ~ "Intermediate",
    #IF they didnt smoke at T1 or T2
    lag(Smoker < 1) & Time == 2 & Smoker < 1 ~ "Ideal", 
    #if NAs
    Time == 1 | Time == 2 & Smoker == NA ~ "Unknown",
  ))
```

If I forgot any combo of T1/T2 pairings just update the `case_when` or let me know and I'll edit the answer

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Participant [3]
  Participant  Time Smoker Health      
        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       
1           1     1      1 Poor        
2           1     2      0 Intermediate
3           2     1      0 Ideal       
4           2     2      0 Ideal       
5           3     1     NA Unknown
```

Comment: Please indicate if this helped

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the delay. It took some playing with, but I did finally get this to work on my larger data set! Thank you so much for your help, and again, sorry for the delayed response.